# How to correctly increment the rate at which segments of a display illuminate via button press

Tags: button, vhdl, fpga, clock, xilinx

I am programming a xilinx basys 3 board in behavioral VHDL. I am illuminating the individual segments of the 4x seven segment display to make it looks as though the display has two rotating "wheels". My overall project consists of many components such as a decoder, mux, debouncer, counter, clock divider for display refresh rate, etc. All of which have been cleared by my prof.
I am currently working on the component that takes in a 250 Hz clk and an up and down button. The up and down buttons will allow for the incrementation of a counter that is mapped to 11 different prescalar values. These values will then vary a clock divider max step accordingly.

Currently my reset button works. However the up and down buttons just pause the rotation of the segments instead of increasing the rate at which they rotate. I believe this component is the issue but I cannot find out where, within the three processes.

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity wheelClkDiv is
    Port ( btnUp, btnDown, clk, reset : in STD_LOGIC;   
           --up/down/rst buttons and 250Hz clk initialized as inputs
           clkout : out STD_LOGIC
           -- newly divided clock initialized as output         
         );
end wheelClkDiv;

architecture Behavioral of wheelClkDiv is

signal count : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(19 downto 0) := x"00000";   --20 bit count value for clk divider
signal temp : STD_LOGIC := '0';                             --temp store value for clk divider
signal countDiv : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(19 downto 0) := x"00000"; --value given to choose prescalar 
signal btn_counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0110";    --button press counter
begin
    buttonChoose : process(btnUp, btnDown, reset)
        begin
            if(btnUp = '1') then
                btn_counter <= btn_counter + 1;     --add one to count if up button pushed
            elsif(btnDown = '1') then
                btn_counter <= btn_counter - 1;     --subtract one from count if down button pushed
            elsif(reset = '1') then
                btn_counter <="0110";           --set back to middle speed if reset is pushed
            end if;
    end process;

    setDivideCase : process(btn_counter)
        begin
            case btn_counter is    --case statement to choose prescalar based on btn_counter value
                when "0000" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000110010000"; --3.2s cycle
                when "0001" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000100101100"; --2.4s cycle
                when "0010" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000011001000"; --1.6s cycle
                when "0011" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000010010110"; --1.2s cycle
                when "0100" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000001100100"; --0.8s cycle
                when "0101" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000001001011"; --0.6s cycle
                when "0110" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000000110010"; --0.4s cycle
                when "0111" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000000100110"; --0.3s cycle
                when "1000" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000000011001"; --0.2s cycle
                when "1001" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000000010011"; --0.15s cycle
                when "1010" => 
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000000001101"; --0.1s cycle     
                when others =>
                    countDiv <= b"00000000000000001101";--not correct
            end case;      
    end process;

    wheelDivider : process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if(reset = '1') then    --reset clock count if reset pushed
            count <= x"00000";
            temp <= '0';
        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then    
            if(count = countDiv) then    --set clk counter value to prescalar
                count <= x"00000";
                temp <= not temp;            
            else
                count <= count + 1;   --keep incrementing clk count until it matches PS
                temp <= temp;
            end if;
        end if;
   end process;
   clkout <= temp;  --give temp value to output clk 
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Process `buttonChoose` isn't synthesis eligible - simulated behavior won't match synthesized. On the board `btn_counter` will act as a gated oscillator `btn_counter` a latch, the two buttons enables, arithmetic providing feedback inverting at least one bit. and the oscillation rate of individual bits controlled by combinatorial delay. This appears consistent with your scant observed behavior description. The historic way to solve this is to produce one clock long events for each button push and making `btn_counter` clock edge driven, ORing the one clock events as an enable.

Comment: (A counter based debouncer using your 250 Hz clock can be modified to produce a one clock long event.)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that you ignore the fact the `count` signal is constantly counting.
When you hit reset, your `count` is back at `x"00000", this is the only reason it works.

But when you hit up/down button, you change the `countDiv` value from e.g.

```
countDiv <= b"00000000000000110010"; --0.4s cycle
```

to

```
countDiv <= b"00000000000000011001"; --0.2s cycle
```

but what if, in the moment of button click, the `count` is `b"00000000000000100000"` ?
The `count = countDiv` condition did not caught before, and not it will never catch. The count will start to count infinitely, and any further changes of `countDiv` won't change that fact (maybe will if you hit other button fast enough and expect of `reset` button of course). The `clkout` will stop at current value and display will freeze, until of course `count` overflows.

Of course the easiest resolution would be changing `count = countDiv` to `count >= countDiv`, but such comparison is resources consuming, so it is not good way to design fpgas. You should reset `count` value to zero every time you chage `countDiv`, or even better, count down to zero, starting at `countDiv`. Then temporary overflowing current `countDiv` should not be a problem. You have plenty of possibilities.

For example:

```
wheelDivider : process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if(reset = '1') then    --reset clock count if reset pushed
            count <= b"00000000000001001011";
            temp <= '0';
        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then    
            if(count = x"00000") then    --set clk counter value to zero
                count <= countDiv;
                temp <= not temp;            
            else
                count <= count - 1;   --keep decrementing count until zero
                temp <= temp;
            end if;
        end if;
end process;
```

I am not sure if this is the only problem for now. Hope it is.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I sort of understand what you are saying but not fully. Is there any way you could provide me with more code of what to change instead of a description of how to change it?

Comment: @DrewP I have updated my answer with code example, hope it clarifies. Now if you update `countDiv` during count down nothing will happened, but when `count` achieves zero, new countdown will start from updated `countDiv` value.

Comment: You could also cure this by using `count >= CountDiv` for detecting when to set count to 0. Counting down is superior, detecting zero is simpler hardware. You'd also want transitions on CountDiv to be clock synchronous, otherwise you don't know what you'll get.  `count` will get optimized to 9 bits in synthesis the count can only go to 4.088 s.